# how to rotate a textView in android?

Tags: android, rotation, textview

How to rotate a **textview** with **180 degrees** rotated in Android?
As some games that the half of screen rotated 180 degrees for 2nd player

as you can see in this picture

[image]

Comment: @RapunzelVanWinkle thanks :) so easy way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use rotate function in xml

```
android:rotation="-180"
```

for dynamic use

```
textview.setRotation(-180);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have made this custom textview i have same requirement like you hope this will help you..just change degree values as per your need..

```
 public class VerticalTextView extends TextView {

        final boolean topDown;

        public VerticalTextView( Context context,
                                 AttributeSet attrs )
        {
            super( context, attrs );
            final int gravity = getGravity();
            if ( Gravity.isVertical( gravity )
                    && ( gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK )
                    == Gravity.BOTTOM )
            {
                setGravity(
                        ( gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK )
                                | Gravity.TOP );
                topDown = false;
            }
            else
            {
                topDown = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec,
                                  int heightMeasureSpec )
        {
            super.onMeasure( heightMeasureSpec,
                    widthMeasureSpec );
            setMeasuredDimension( getMeasuredHeight(),
                    getMeasuredWidth() );
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas )
        {
            TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
            textPaint.setColor( getCurrentTextColor() );
            textPaint.drawableState = getDrawableState();

            canvas.save();

            if ( topDown )
            {
                canvas.translate( getWidth(), 0 );
                canvas.rotate( 90 );
            }
            else
            {
                canvas.translate( 0, getHeight() );
                canvas.rotate( -90 );
            }

            canvas.translate( getCompoundPaddingLeft(),
                    getExtendedPaddingTop() );

            getLayout().draw( canvas );
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }
```

If you still need help please inform me

Answer (score 0):

To rotate TextView, use:

```
 android:rotation="180"
```

Place this within the required Textview tags.